# WMI Access Denied Problem on 2003 Server

Tags: c#, wmi

I´m having a problem whenever i try to use WMI services on a virtual pc running a 2003 Server.

The error message that i get is 'Access Denied'. I have already checked the permissions of the user over the COM components. The curious thing is that i´m running both WMI service and my app as Administrator user, so i don´t think i have trouble with permissions.

Can Anyone help me??

Thanks you very much.

The problem is on this block:

```
         ManagementEventWatcher watcher;
        try
        {
            numeros = devolverRandomicos();
            string nros = "";
            foreach (int num in numeros)
            {
                nros = nros + "  " + num.ToString();
            }
            MessageBox.Show(nros);
            watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher("root\\OnGuard", dataQry);
            watcher.EventArrived += WMIEventArrieved;
            watcher.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR CREANDO EL WATCHER: \n" + e.Message,"CatchToyota",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Comment: What is dataQry's value? Just an example will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem at last was in the Domain Users I was using to log in. After getting the machine out of the domain, all started to work just fine.

I guess it was a problem with permissions on domain users.